# React event processing

Tags: reactjs

Consider an edit box. User types some text. There is a key-press handler attached, which does something like:

```
setState({echo: this.state.echo + event.char})
```

Is it possible that in initial state `{echo: “”}`, the user types “a” then “b”, React calls `onKeyPress(“a”)`, which calls `setState({echo: “a”})`, and then - before setState is actually applied by `React - React calls onKeyPress(“b”)`?

You see a problem with that, right? `OnKeyPress(“b”)` will see the same old state `{echo: “”}` as `OnKeyPress(“a”)` did, and will issue`setState({echo: “”+“b”})`, which is `setState({echo: “b”})` - while we obviously wanted `{echo: “ab”}`

- My tests show me that the second event handler does not get called before first `setStat`e is completely processed. But a few tests may lie, unlike some documented contract.
- I realize that this problem has solutions, like using form `setState( state => …)`
- But I still want to know: is this situation possible or not. Maybe synthetic event handlers are guaranteed to only be executed when all pending `setState` processing (caused by previous handler) is done? If so, where can I read some proof of that? A specific location in some manual, or qualified answer posted on the Web… Or, maybe, it’s the opposite that is true - that no such guarantees exist (however if that’s the case, “simple” form of setState is sure to cause bugs and they should not allow this form at all).

Comment: Did you see that `setState` also accepts a function with the previous state?

Comment: "I realize that this problem has solutions, like using form setState( state => …)"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it's the second time I get no clear answer to similar question, I can only deduce there is at least a theoretical possibility of the mentioned scenario. Then we better follow the documentation in all cases and only infer next state from previous one with a function-based setState.

Comment: This makes us go even further. If there is some logic in any event handler which makes decisions basing on current state and sets a new state, it's probably a good idea to extract it all to a method and pass the whole method to setState. And this in turn leads to an idea about extracting all those methods to separate component carrying all the "real" logic, with the original component only left with markup and stub event handlers (and without any state), with real logic and "state" injected into it via props. Which is, give or take, the approach with presentational and container objects.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` will always be in order, but the argument you give it can rely on state that is from the past. `setState` calls (such as from your two key presses) *can* be merged and called on a next cycle.

That's the reason the solution you mention in point two exists and is the correct way to solve this. The way you describe in your question, simply concatting the state value and the pressed key, is exactly what the docs [advise against](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: Granted, setState calls can be merged. But if it's known for sure that next onKeyPress invocation will only happen after processing all pending setState() calls, then it's no problem, because that means the only mergeable setState() calls are ones executed from within the same handler invocation: onKeyPress calls setState then again setState (maybe indirectly), then all those state changes are processed (probably after being merged), and only then the next onKeyPress() is invoked. And whether it's known for sure or not - is exactly the question I am asking here.

Comment: I mean, it's my fault if I wrote such a code that executed multiple setState calls within same handler invocation with no awareness of its asynchronous nature. You just don't do that :) But being unable to call setState in multiple consequent invocations of the event handler is another thing entirely.

Comment: All right, this place in documentation you are referring to, it's very clear about how we should not use current state for composing new state. But if we knew that all pending setState are processed before invoking next event handler, or something like that, then we could say that in this particular scenario we can use current state. But of course if no such information exists, then we must assume it's unsafe (like the docs say in general).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you leverage the component lifecycle methods componentDidUpdate and componentWillUpdate.  In between these methods, there will be a render cycle.  This allows you to respond to things that were changed.

Instead of trying to append the current keypress character to the existing string at the time of capturing the key, try appending the character in componentDidUpdate().

In that case, you would just store the current keypress in state (currKey, for example). Then in componentDidUpdate(), you can add something like this:

```javascript
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { currKey, echo } = this.state;
  if (currKey !== '') {
    this.setState({
      echo: echo + currKey, // append the current key to echo
      currKey: '' // reset the current key
    });
  }
}
```

The setState here will trigger another update round, however in that round currKey will be empty, which means the logic will not execute again until another key is pressed.

Comment: I suppose this can be done, however like I mentioned before (and recently did it again) I am aware that there are other approaches. But I am asking about this particular one! If it's known for sure if the situation is possible, or it's known for sure it is not possible, or nothing is known for sure.

Comment: Also, I am not even sure it's a good idea to respond to componentDidUpdate by making further state changes.

Comment: I agree it can be dangerous and often linting rules warn against it.  However, in this case, it is safe and won't produce an infinite loop.